# How to reduce javascript code that use JQuery and .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, selector

I have tried to reduce following code

```
var wgDialog 
    = jQuery(".ui-dialog.ui-overlay-visible",window.parent.document)
        .each
            (function(nIndex)
                {
                var sWidgetName = $(this).attr('data-widgetvar');
                var wgDialog = window.parent.PF(sWidgetName);
                });
```

to this code

```
var jqDialog 
    = jQuery(".ui-dialog.ui-overlay-visible",window.parent.document)
        .children(":first-child");

var sWidgetName = jqDialog.attr('data-widgetvar');
var wgDialog = window.parent.PF(sWidgetName);
```

but this doesn't work !

The `sWidgetName` variable is always undefined in last code.

What is my mistake ?

Comment: Your 2nd *adds* `.children` so the first loops through all the `.ui-dialog` elements while the 2nd takes the first child of each of the dialogs.  Then `.attr` takes from the first element of those.

Comment: Need to know the html to answer this question. But the first child of element  `.ui-dialog.ui-overlay-visible` doesn't have an attribute named `data-widgetvar`. You could try to add the element name of the first child of thats an option for you. `.children("div:first-child");` for example.

Comment: The First and Second code performs completely different operations. The first one iterates through all the .ui-dialog elements where as second one just gets the attribute 'data-widgetvar' of the first child of the first .ui-dialog element. What do you want to reduce in the First Code?

Answer (score 1):

With help of comments, I have found a solution.

I must use get(0) to obtain first element in list returner by JQuery().

And I must use `$(jqDialog)` instead of `jqDialog` to get 'data-widgetvar' attribute.

Here is my new code

```
var jqDialog 
    = jQuery(".ui-dialog.ui-overlay-visible",window.parent.document)
        .get(0);

var sWidgetName = $(jqDialog).attr('data-widgetvar');
var wgDialog = window.parent.PF(sWidgetName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to access an element with attribute `data-widgetvar` nested in an element having css classes `ui-dialog` and `ui-overlay-visible` you could do the following with plain javascript:

```
var myElement = document.querySelector('.ui-dialog.ui-overlay-visible [data-widgetvar]');
```

`querySelector` allows a CSS like selector combining class together with attribute selector.

**Update**:

Here is a working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function main() {
            var myElement = document.querySelector('.ui-dialog.ui-overlay-visible [data-widgetvar]');
            console.log("Attribute value", myElement.getAttribute('data-widgetvar'));
        }

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", main);        
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="ui-dialog ui-overlay-visible">
        <div>some element</div>
        <div data-widgetvar="someValue">some text content</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have tried your solution in replacing myElement by jqDialog but this doesn't work. I have tried some little change without success. I have already a solution but I'm interesting to verify yours. Can you send me how to assign jqDialog line ?